# How to check with ngif if the email pattern doesn't match

Tags: angular

How to check whether the patter matches the email entered in the input field.

```
<input type="email" name="email" #email ngModel required [pattern]="emailPattern" placeholder="Email *"/>
    <div *ngIf="validateEmail(email)">Email not valid</div>
```

.ts file

```
pattern = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
validateEmail(email) {
if (email == pattern) {
return true;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [validate email on angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902766/validate-email-on-angular-4)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use reactive forms, and the built-in validators. The basic/bare minimum structure is as follows:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'user',
  styleUrls: ['user.component.scss'],
  template: `

<form novalidate [formGroup]="form">
     <label for="Email">Email: </label> 
     <input type="text" formControlName="Email">
</form>
`
})
export class User {

  form = this.fb.group({
    Email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
  })

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}
}
```

This requires that the user enters an email, and ensures it matches a standard email pattern using the built-in validator.